# B/w plot with white background

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I need to change background in a plot created as follows:

```
df.plot(x='Week', y='Frequency')
```

Data:

```
Week    Frequency
0   2020-01-05  0
1   2020-01-12  0
2   2020-01-19  0
3   2020-01-26  3
4   2020-02-02  32
5   2020-02-09  17
6   2020-02-16  23
7   2020-02-23  53
8   2020-03-01  59
9   2020-03-08  92
10  2020-03-15  89
11  2020-03-22  10
```

I tried to use facecolors='white' in the formula above, but I got an error as the property is not recognised.
I would need to create a b/w chart with no grid and with white colour background.
To remove the grid, I am using this code:

```
plt.grid(b=None)
```

Can you please tell me how to include b/w and background info?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in matplotlib.  Try using: plt.style.use('dark_background')

Comment: I would need a white background, so probably the style you mentioned is not what I am looking for. How can I go back to my original one? Now it is with a black background

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.set_axis_bgcolor`:

```
p = df.plot(x='Week', y='Frequency')
p.set_axis_bgcolor("COLOR")
p.show()
```

Comment: I am getting this error: AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'set_axis_bgcolor'. It should be fixed with p.set_facecolor("white") but the problem is that, after tried the other solution, I have some parts of plot black :(

Answer (score 0):

it is some bug, but

```
df.plot(kind="pie",y='...',xticks=[0])
```

worked for me to change bgcolor of plot to white (easy way)

if you want to control the figure, you should create it:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_facecolor('white')
ax.set_title("...")
df.plot(ax=ax, kind="pie", y='...')
```

in my case (i use dark theme) i just use white text color:

```
ax = df.plot(
    kind="pie",
    y='...',
    autopct='%1.1f%%',
    wedgeprops={'linewidth':1,'edgecolor':'white'},
    textprops={'color':'white'}
    ) 
ax.set_title("...",color='white',size=16);
```